# problema con slash al guardar una ruta en mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql

Buen día,

espero me puedan dar una mano... Requiero guardar una ruta de un archivo en MySql con PHP

ya he intentado usar // como he leído en otros sitios

aqui el codigo

```
 <?php

    mkdir("../uploads/solicitudes/solicitud".$nuevo_id2, 0700);

    //este directorio me lo crea a la perfeccion por lo cual se que no es 
//problema de php si no de MySql, en $nuevo_id2 tengo almacenado un numero 
//unico para cada subida, es decir creo un directorio nuevo para cada subida, 
//quedando por ejemplo "../uploads/solicitudes/solicitud15" lo que necesito 
//es guardar esa ruta en la base de datos

    //despues tengo la misma ruta que creé arriba en otra variable

    $upload_folder ='../uploads/solicitudes/solicitud'.$nuevo_id2;

    //y aquí inserto datos donde va la ruta tambien

    $agregar_info_usuario = mysql_query("UPDATE  `tecflucol`.`solicitudes` SET  `nombre` =  '$nombre', `ruta_cedula` =  '$upload_folder' WHERE  `solicitudes`.`id` ='$nuevo_id2';

    ?>
```

el problema es que me guarda ../uploads/

el resto lo elimina

alguna idea?

Comment: Has revisado el tamaño de datos del campo en la base de datos, has probado con comillas dobles asi  `$upload_folder ="../uploads/solicitudes/solicitud".$nuevo_id2;`

Comment: @Kevin gracias amigo, era el tamaño... pasé por alto eso

Comment: Ok, Te recomiendo usar consultas preparadas pare evitar la inyección sql, tu código es vulnerable. saludos